# Accordion doesn't open properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this accordion. Everything is ok except opening. When I press one, it opens both. I need to open just that one which I click and when I click second I want to hide first. Need to make it toggle

When I change display:flex to column it works properly but in row it opens both on click. It doesn't make sense for me what is logic behind it.

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accordion-list > li > .answer').hide();
    
  $('.accordion-list > li').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).removeClass("active").find(".answer").slideUp();
    } else {
      $(".accordion-list > li.active .answer").slideUp();
      $(".accordion-list > li.active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active").find(".answer").slideDown();
    }
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

```css
ul.accordion-list {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f9f9fa;
  }
  ul.accordion-list li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F36F20;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
  }
  ul.accordion-list li.active h3:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  ul.accordion-list li h3 {
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  ul.accordion-list li div.answer {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  ul.accordion-list li div.answer p {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 150%;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion-list">
            <li>
              <h3>info</h3>
              <div class="answer">
                <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                    <tr style="background-color: #F36F20; color: #fff;">
                        <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkjkj</td>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjjkjk</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjjkkj:</td>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjk</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #F36F20; color: #fff;">
                        <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkjk:</td>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjk</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkj:</td>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjkj</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #F36F20; color: #fff;">
                        <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkjkj:</td>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjk</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkjkj</td>
                        <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjkjj,00€</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                  
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h3>second</h3>
                <div class="answer">
                    <table style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                        <tr style="background-color: #F36F20; color: #fff;">
                            <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkj</td>
                            <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjkjk</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">jkkjk</td>
                            <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">kjkjlj</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="background-color: #F36F20; color: #fff;">
                            <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">kjkljlk</td>
                            <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">jlklkjljk€</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="cell" style="float: left; padding-left: 1rem;">ljklkjljk:</td>
                            <td class="cell" style="float: right; padding-right: 1rem;">20.12.2025</td>
                        </tr>
    
                    </table>                 
                </div>
              </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: try `each()` method

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov the jquery is working fine. It is a CSS problem.

Comment: @PranavRustagi, ok, sorry. And I gave you a solution. Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a jQuery problem but a CSS one.

I've been experimenting in JSFiddle and changing the height of the LI from auto to min-content seems to work:

```
height: min-content;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6w9j84rm/

You can clearly see the effect by disabling the jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

It is a CSS problem. The parent is flex, that is why it is giving all the available space to li when set to `auto`. Just set height of li to `fit-content` or `min-content` or `max-content`:

```
ul.accordion-list li {
  height: fit-content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the rule `margin-bottom: auto` for `ul.accordion-list li`. This rule has excellent cross-browser compatibility!

And it works well.

It should be like this:

```
ul.accordion-list li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #F36F20;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;

    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Comment: This jquery code will not yield same result.

Comment: why such a conclusion?

Comment: Take a case where you click on a li with class active